# drupal editing user information after registration

Tags: drupal, registration

how to allow user to edit their information after registration. And moreover how add new fields during editing information.

for ex: my primary registration holds name,email,picture(optional). I want to get additional information like state,city,... when they wants some customized service.

May any one suggest me a solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) + profile, or cck + content_profile